# angular2 service - RXjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

how i prevent an error while trynig to get item by id - if i refresh the page- this is the code:

the service code:

```
 getServices(): Observable <any> {
        return this._http.get(this.APIURL + 'serives.json')
            .map((resposne: Response) => <any> resposne.json())
            .do(data => {
                this.services = data
            })
            .catch(this.hendelError)
    }

getService(id): any {
    let myService;
    if (this.services.length) {
        myService = this.services.filter(service => service.id === id);
        return myService;
    } else {
        this.getServices().subscribe(
            data => {
                myService = this.services.filter(service => service.id === id);
                return myService;
            }
        )
    }

}

private hendelError(error: Response) {
    console.log('error', error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'server error');
}
```

and the component code is:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    if(this._manager.services.length){
      this.services = this._manager.services;
      return;
    }else{
      this._manager.getServices()
          .subscribe(
              data => {this.services = data;
                console.log('data',data);}
          )
    }
  }
```

and when i refresh the page i get this error:

`main.bundle.js:46117 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./ServicedetailsComponent class ServicedetailsComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property '0' of undefi`ned

Comment: Show complete Component and its Template.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 is not "refresh the page" friendly. When you refresh the page, you reload your app.

The solution is to pass all the context in path (using a Router) and sessionStorage (or localStorage). Then you will be able to reload the app in the current context.